# Solr - nested entity with multiple values

Tags: solr

Once more..
I have 2 tables 'blog' and 'comment'. A blog can contains n comments (blog --1:n-- comment). Up to date I use following select to insert the data into solr index:

```
    <entity name="blog" dataSource="mssqlDatasource" pk="id"
        transformer="ClobTransformer"
        query="SELECT b.id, b.market, b.title AS blogTitle, b.message AS            
                blogMessage, c.message AS commentMessage, c.secondColumn 
                FROM blog b LEFT JOIN comment c ON b.id = c.source_id
                AND c.source_type = 'blog'">
        <field column="blogMessage" name="blogMessage" clob="true" />
        <field column="commentMessage" name="commentMessage" clob="true" />
    </entity>
```

The index result looks like:

```
    <doc>
     <str name="id">1</str>
     <str name="market">12</str>
     <str name="title">blog of title 1</str>
     <str name="blogMessage">message of blog 1</str>
     <str name="commentMessage">message of comment</str>
     <str name="scondColumn">Im the second column from comment</str>
    </doc>

    <doc>
     <str name="id">1</str>
     <str name="market">12</str>
     <str name="title">blog of title 1</str>
     <str name="blogMessage">message of blog 1</str>
     <str name="commentMessage">message of comment - Im the second comment</str>
     <str name="scondColumn">Im the second column from comment</str>       
    </doc>
```

I would say this is stupid because I got too many index data with the same blog just the comments are different. Is it possible to set 'comments' as 'subentity' like following:

```
    <entity name="blog" dataSource="mssqlDatasource" pk="id"
        transformer="ClobTransformer"
        query="SELECT b.id, b.market, b.title AS blogTitle, b.message AS            
                blogMessage
                FROM blog b">
         <field column="blogMessage" name="blogMessage" clob="true" />

          <entity name="comment" dataSource="mssqlDatasource" pk="id"
             transformer="ClobTransformer"
             query="SELECT c.message as commentMessage, c.secondColumn
                FROM comment c
                WHERE c.source_id = ${blog.id}">
            <field column="commentMessage" name="commentMessage" clob="true" />              
          </entity>
    </entity>
```

Is that possible? How would the result looks like (cant test it until monday)?

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, if you want to fill a multi-valued comment field for each blog document, you want the [CachedSqlEntityProcessor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#CachedSqlEntityProcessor)

Mine tend to look a lot like this (I'm leaving out the clob transformer bits, but you obviously need them)

```
<entity name="blog" 
        query="SELECT b.id, 
                      b.market, 
                      b.title AS blogTitle, 
                      b.message AS            
               blogMessage
               FROM blog b">
    <entity name="blog_comment" 
            query="SELECT c.message as commentMessage, 
                          c.secondColumn,
                          c.blog_id
            FROM comment c" 
     processor="CachedSqlEntityProcessor"  
     where="blog_id=blog.id"/>    
<entity>
```

The docs should look like:

```
<doc>
   <str name="id">1</str>
   <str name="market">12</str>
   <str name="title">blog of title 1</str>
   <str name="blogMessage">message of blog 1</str>
   <arr name="commentMessage">
       <str>message of comment</str>
       <str>message of comment - Im the second comment</str>
   </arr>
   <arr name="secondColumn">
       <str>Im the second column from comment</str>
       <str>Im the second column from comment</str>
   </arr>
</doc>
```

You may want to do multiple nested entities, one that queries for each column, if you want to avoid repeating values.